# Variable that is equal to 1 is apparently equal to 0

Tags: c, multithreading

I am getting very frustrated with a strange error I am receiving, maybe someone has an idea as to what is going on.

```
while(dirQLength != 0 && j<M){
      if(j == M-1)
         lastDirThread = 1;
      error6 = pthread_create(&(dir_tid[j]), NULL, &threadTaskDir, NULL);
      if (error6 != 0)
         printf("\nThread can't be created :[%s]", strerror(error6));
      j++;
      printf("dirQLength: %d\nZero: %d\n", dirQLength, 0);
      if(dirQLength == 0)
         puts("WHHHHYYYY?");
}
```

The output of this code being run is as follows:

[image]

Any help will do. I was making some last-minute adjustments to a project and it feels ridiculous that this is my hang-up.

Comment: Is your thread function modifying `dirQLength`?  If so, you have a race condition.

Comment: Does the code you are running in the thread modify `dirQLength`?

Comment: There could also be a buffer overflow in the thread, which is modifying `dirQLength` inadvertently.

Comment: Oh interesting, yes the thread does modify dirQLength. It is necessary, is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: synchronize the threads and fix the race condition! If you've got a critical section, protect the access as necessary.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the thread callback function as well as all relevant declarations - those of variables shared with threads in particular. Then your question can be answered.